# How to make a keylogger on Android with adb?

Tags: android, adb, keylogger

Is there a way to see all screen touch's from my Android device on my PC  with adb?
Like every time that I touch the screen, it will print me where I touched the screen.

Comment: What did you do to achieve this? Show your code/efforts here.StackOverflow is not a code writing service. If you have a problem with your code, please provide Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: what I won't to get is the places's thet I touch in x,y like every time I touch the screen it will print me you touched on 350 670

Comment: Read about the /dev/input/event files on Android, it's a good place to start.

Comment: thank's for the answer but I already checkt it and I don't see ther a option to get the touch in x and y

Answer (score 0):

By using this code you can log your touch events

```
public class Sniffer extends Activity {

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_X);
        float y = event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_Y);

        Log.i("t...OUCH: ", x + " " + y);

        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);

    }
}
```

if you want in service refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26574587/4394827)